# How to resolve gVim startup error "No D-BUS daemon running"

Tags: gvim, error

Stating gnome-vim from the terminal on Linux Mint 17.3 I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred while loading or saving configuration information for gvim. Some of your configuration settings may not work properly.
>
> No D-BUS daemon running

[image: gvim dialog error No D-BUS daemon running]

This error recently started on my system. I believe the issue is external to Vim, possibly dbus is not functional correctly anymore, or another program is impacting it.

### Current Workaround

I determined that if you relaunch dbus in the terminal it can resolve the issue.

```
export $(dbus-launch)
```

Does anyone have a more permanent solution?

Comment: I can't find any references to `dbus` in the Vim source tree, so I'm not sure where this error is coming from... I suspect it's coming from `libgnome` or some such... At any rate, I think you're better off asking this on [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com).